# Meteor Upload File associated to a collection

Tags: javascript, http, upload, meteor

I am trying to upload a image file while I post some text in a form, to a collection. i am using this [meteorite package](http://collectionfs.github.io/Meteor-CollectionFS/)

I am still new to meteor, and am Persisting in javascript but still learning lots. The post will go through but I don't know why the image wont upload to the cfs folder. I would also like to know Once I get the image uploaded worked how to retrieve the url to the associated collection post? Thanks

My Code Below

PUBLICATIONS

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function() {
  return Posts.find();
});

Meteor.publish('myPostsFiles', function() {
    if (this.userId) {
        return PostsFS.find({ owner: this.userId }, { limit: 30 });
    }
});
```

COLLECTIONS

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');

PostsFS = new CollectionFS('posts', { autopublish: false });
```

SUBSCRIPTIONS

```
Meteor.subscribe('myPostsFiles');
```

ROUTES AND EMBDED SUBSCRIPTIONS

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'hello',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  waitOn: function() {
    return [ Meteor.subscribe('posts'), Meteor.subscribe('comments'), Meteor.subscribe('myPostsFiles')];
  }

});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('postList', {path: '/'});
  this.route('postPage', {
    path: '/posts/:_id',
    data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }

  });
  this.route('postSubmit', {
    path: '/post'
  });

});
```

SUBMIT TEMPLATE

```
<template name="postSubmit">

  <form>
    <textarea name="postA" type="text" value=""/>
    <input name="files" type="file" class="fileUploader" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

  </form>
</template>
```

SUBMIT TEMPLATE JS

```
Template.postSubmit.events({

  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();



      var files = e.target.files;
      for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
          PostsFS.storeFile(f);
      }

    var post = {

      postA: $(e.target).find('[name=postA]').val()
    }

    post._id = Posts.insert(post);
    Router.go('postPage', post);
  }
});
```

Comment: I am looking to do the same. You got this working?